# Sharing same properties of ViewController for iPhone Stroryboard and iPad Story Board

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, universal

I'm developing a universal application.
in the first view, I have the login screen for the user.
In iPhone storyBoard, I have added 2 text field and one button( login check).
I have added properties in ViewController.h file by dragging those objects(Ctrl key + Dragg) to .h file.
I have added code for login check and it is working fine for iPhone.

This is the code in ViewController.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtUserId;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtUserPwd;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnLogin;
```

In the iPad storyBoard, I have added 2 text field( userid and password) and i button for login.
So now, I want to bind those objects with the veriable which I declared already in ViewController.h file in case of iPhone.

My questions:
1. What is the right way to bind properties for both storyboard?
2. Am I on the right direction or should I think in a different way to do it?

I am new with iPhone development. Please help.

Thanks.
--Amin

Answer (score 0):

Give your custom class name to storyboard from storyboard utility.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure to link both the storyboards with your Login class. Now go to iPad storyboard, right click the view components and drag them and hover on to the properties you have declared already.

Comment: Thanks. I added my ViewController to the iPadstory board and bind the objects to the property and its working now.

Comment: Glad to know that it helped. You may accept the answer.. :)